# An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, single-page-application

When running the terminal commands ng server or ng serve I'm getting this issue:

An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check in your package.json to see if you have this package in your devDependencies section or not

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.18"
}
```

If exist try to

delete package-lock.json or yarn-lock.json

run

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then run

```
npm i
```

Comment: what happen in npm i ??

Answer (score 1):

Install **@angular-devkit/build-angular** as dev dependency.

> npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

or,

> yarn add @angular-devkit/build-angular --dev

Answer (score 1):

This error (Unhandled exception for a module) occurs when ***node_modules*** folder does not exist inside the project, or when the folder exists, but does not contain all the dependencies downloaded.

**$ npm install** command will download all the dependencies into the **node_modules** folder of the proejct.

***npm install*** is automatically triggered in the background by the '***ng new***', at the time of creation of the angular project.

The other angular commands like '***ng build***' or '***ng serve***' commands assume that 'ng new' had completed successfully.

If, for some reason, the ***npm install*** failed at the time of creation, or if the ***node_modules*** folder got deleted after the project was created, then the other angular commands (ng serve, ng build, ...) will generate this 'Unhandled Exception'.

Manually executing the ***npm install*** command inside the project will download the dependencies and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure  `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0"` is available in `devDependencies` of `package.json` before running npm install in your angular root directory.