# I get this error:Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json when I try run my app with ng serve from Linux

Tags: angular

hello guys I have this next error when I try run my App from the terminal(linux), when I run this command:

> ng serve

and I get this error in my terminal:

```html
AppBlog/blog# ng serve
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve-impl.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
See "/tmp/ng-ev5aDi/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

then  i checked out this part :

**An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'**

this part say that cannot find moduled called: "'@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'"

then I cheked out this file in my project but I have this, look:

```html
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
```

then i went to google and search and I found this like from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59136899/an-unhandled-exception-occurred-could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-an)  and I tried their solution but it does not work and I run the command ng serve again.

what I did wrong?

before nothing , before I added 3 components: login,register and home in my folder : **src/app**   with this command : **ng generate component login** and I import my component in my file : app.component.ts this way:

```js
/* THIS IS JUST A EXAMPLE VERY SIMILAR TO MY CODE REAL,  I just import one component*/

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { loginComponent } from './login.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  declarations: [loginComponent], //import my login
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'blog';
}
```

maybe is this part but I dont find a solution, any expert in angular could tell me what I did wrong?

**UPDATE**

I am continue searching in google and I found this:
[github/Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10745) they are saying that I would install npm/angular-cli/node again and I run this command for update my angular cli:

> #### uninstalled ang-cli
>
> npm uninstall @angular/cli

> #### installed the latest
>
> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

but first I update my npm with this command:

> #### installed the latest npm
>
> npm install -g npm@latest

but it still does not work.

Comment: did you try reinstalling the module? Also downgrade to a version below and check

Comment: @prosper1 when I try update or reinstall the module with this next command : npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59136899/an-unhandled-exception-occurred-could-not-find-module-angular-devkit-build-an), I get this error or message i mean : npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

Comment: Did you tried to delete the folder "node_modules" and install all the dependencies other time with npm install --save?

Comment: The solution you describe in UPDATE worked for me.

Comment: you need to check the version of node.
@angular/cli ~9.0.3 will only work with node ^10.13.0 || ^12.11.0
see: https://runebook.dev/ru/docs/angular/guide/versions

Answer (score 18):

Please try installing the npm on a project folder. I had installed npm globally but installing the npm once again on a solution folder fixed my issue.

`npm install` in the project folder will do the trick. Then do `ng serve -o`

Comment: `npm install` in the solution folder will do the trick. Then do `ng serve -o`

Comment: What does the '-o' do in the 'ng serve -o'?

Comment: @EvanSevy opens a browser to the app

Answer (score 14):

I finally found something working for me.

Add `--force` at the end of your npm command.

Like  `npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular --force`

Then `ng serve`

Answer (score 8):

In my case these 2 commands helped:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 5):

I have faced this issue when i recently upgraded the Angular CLI to Angular 9.
the following commands fixed the issue.

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
npm install
ng serve -o
```

Comment: when i do that i get the below error ```npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...@types/node/-/node-6.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rmahapatra\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-11T11_04_56_358Z-debug.log```

Answer (score 5):

If you are on Angular 11 and facing this issue then please do the following:

1. Remove `"@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build"` dependency from ***devDependencies***
2. Update ***angular.json***->projects->your-library-name -> architect -> build ->

   **Old:**`"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",`

   **New:**`"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",`

Comment: I may be on an older version 9. But I used "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build" here and it worked. Thanks for the hint on the builder within angular.json

Comment: Thanks, finally to much scrolling to find this answer. Angular team, why not add this in the migrations?

Answer (score 2):

In my case running  `npm install` in project folder solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case 2 commands helped:

`npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular`

`npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/core`

Answer (score 0):

Under the project directory run the following command

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Answer (score 0):

The error states that "Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'" which means you have to have that package added.

1. install the latest npm

   npm install -g npm@latest
2. add the missing

   npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact issue on an existing Angular 10 project. The following steps resolved the issue for me:

1. Delete the `package-lock.json` file.
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder and all of its contents.
3. Run `npm install`. Note that in my case I had to add the `--force` flag. YMMV

At this point, `ng build --prod` completed successfully for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am Working Angular Project When I update Angular Cli and then I get this error
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/utils'
Require stack:

- C:\codeFlies Development\how_marketsapp\node_modules@ionic\angular-toolkit\builders\utils\index.js
- C:\codeFlies Development\how_marketsapp\node_modules@ionic\angular-toolkit\builders\cordova-build\index.js
- C:\codeFlies Development\how_marketsapp\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\codeFlies Development\how_marketsapp\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\codeFlies Development\how_marketsapp\node_modules@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\codeFlies Development\how_marketsapp\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\run-impl.js
- C:\codeFlies Development\how_marketsapp\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\codeFlies Development\how_marketsapp\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\codeFlies Development\how_marketsapp\node_modules@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\codeFlies Development\how_marketsapp\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\codeFlies Development\how_marketsapp\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\codeFlies Development\how_marketsapp\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng
  See "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-UQJuET\angular-errors.log" for further details.

I have resolve this error by using this command

> npm i @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting a similar but different error.

```
Cannot find module '@nguniversal/builders/package.json'
```

To fix it I had to run

```
npm install --save-dev @nguniversal/builders
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using:

```
npm i --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular --force
npm i @angular/compiler-cli --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Earlier following were errors:-

[ng serve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glbjh.png)

Following worked for me: -

[npm install npm@latest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAxVw.png)  reinstall without -g

[Packages installed successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE3lC.png)

Comment: Please, try to avoid using images with code and errors, put it as code in your answer instead

Answer (score 0):

It also happened to me, when I `ng serve` on the cloned code on the company. This happens because there's an error with node modules installation so we need to install it again, build it, and serve it.

1. npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
2. ng build
3. ng serve

If the first step above, didn't work because it didn't work to me and receives another error which is: "npm ERR! cb() never called!"
I solve this using this command: `npm cache clean --force`
and once this worked, continue to steps 2-3. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I personally took 2 days to have a solution for this problem, that was after I upgraded my angular version.

`npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular --force`

It saved my day!

Answer (score -1):

`npm install`
run this in your terminal and done.