# Unable to load schema problem in angular.json file

Tags: json, angular, npm, npm-install

I have a problem in angular.json file.

```
{
    "resource": "/e:/P dev/project/Resume_generator/front/angular.json",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
    "code": "768",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Unable to load schema from 'e:\\P dev\\project\\Resume_generator\\front\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\lib\\config\\schema.json': ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'e:\\P dev\\project\\Resume_generator\\front\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\lib\\config\\schema.json'.",
    "startLineNumber": 2,
    "startColumn": 14,
    "endLineNumber": 2,
    "endColumn": 66
}
```

After that I tried `npm cache clean` and again I got an error

```
npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Samanthika\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-08T16_01_34_045Z-debug.log

E:\P dev\project\Resume_generator\front>npm cache clean
npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Samanthika\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-08T16_02_04_108Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Enter your project and run the following commands:

- npm install -g @angular/cli
- ng add @angular/cli

Answer (score 0):

Try followings as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60404698/i-get-this-errorcannot-find-module-angular-devkit-build-angular-package-json).

```
npm install -g npm@latest
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Run cache clean with --force

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 0):

First, run this,

```
npm cache clean --force
```

If this is not working, you can delete the **node modules file** and **package-lock.json** file

Then run,

```
npm i
```