# The error output was: An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, angular8

I have created an Angular project with ASP.NET Core in **Visual Studio** and when I run the project then I catch below error :

> The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'

How can I solve this problem?
Any help will be appriciated!

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59136949/11398810)?

Answer (score 0):

add below mentioned dependency in dependencies (package.json) and run "npm install"

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.1",
------------------------------------------
}
```